# Iptables inside Raspberry to access a device in another subnet

Tags: routes, raspberry-pi, iptables

I have a Raspberry PI which I access through Wlan via 192.168.0.48 (see below)
On that raspberry I have connected a USB device (an Adalm Pluto) which creates a virtual eth1 port with address 192.168.1.2
The USB device hosts a web page that I can access when inside the Raspberry via 192.168.1.1

How could I access the same webpage also via Wlan through 192.168.0.xx for instance.
I am sure that this is possible with Iptable, but Just can make it run.

Thanks

Daniel

eth1: flags=4163  mtu 1500

```
    inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::1b51:bbe:8beb:b4c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:e0:22:bf:29:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 212  bytes 141107 (137.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 278  bytes 47853 (46.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536

```
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 17  bytes 1004 (1004.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 17  bytes 1004 (1004.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

wlan0: flags=4163  mtu 1500

```
    inet 192.168.0.48  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::39f6:81b1:bbba:ea77  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:0b:15:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 12406  bytes 7827334 (7.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5956  bytes 2167015 (2.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This question actually belongs to another community because it has nothing to do with software development. I vote to close it down.
Meanwhile here is an answer based on [following article](http://jensd.be/343/linux/forward-a-tcp-port-to-another-ip-or-port-using-nat-with-iptables):

```sh
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.48
```

Linux systems on RPI devices are not special and all debian based online tutorials are applicable to them.
I'm sure you will be able to access your website if you check all steps in tutorial.

There is also user-land way to share your website by using tcp/http proxy (this is not performance wise but is much easier to understand and setup).

```sh
sudo apt install balance
sudo balance 80 192.168.1.1 80
```